# Trying to call functions using a vector of pointers to functions, but it fails to return the correct value--is it my compiler?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, vector, compiler-construction

EDIT:
So it seems like everyone is getting the correct output, so my question is now this: Why am I getting the wrong output? Why is the second argument, y, getting changed to zero, regardless if I use a variable or a literal? And no, I didn't get confused and put the wrong variable, I double checked. I am using Visual Studio 2013.

I'm doing an exercise from the fifth edition of the C++ primer by Lippman, Lajoie, and Moo on page 250, and my code for the third exercise, 6.56, is returning incorrect values.

I made a vector of pointers to function of type int (int, int), made four functions of that type (addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division), and added pointers to them to my vector. I attempted to move through those pointers with an iterator, dereferencing them to call them, but for add2 and subtract, it returned the value of the first argument, 0 for mult, and the else clause for divide, even though y was not equal to 0.

The code is as follows:

```
int test(int x, int y);
int add2(int x, int y);
int subtract(int x, int y);
int mult(int x, int y);
int divide(int x, int y);

typedef decltype(test) *FuncP; //type declaration of a ptr to a function that takes two ints and returns int

int main(){
//6.7
vector<FuncP> ptrsToFuncs;
ptrsToFuncs.push_back(*add2);
ptrsToFuncs.push_back(*subtract);
ptrsToFuncs.push_back(*mult);
ptrsToFuncs.push_back(*divide);

vector<FuncP>::iterator fIter;
int test1 = 6, test2 = 8;
int test3 = 0;

cout << "Running four arithmetic functions with " << test1 << " and " << test2 << "\n\n";

for (fIter = ptrsToFuncs.begin(); fIter != ptrsToFuncs.end(); ++fIter)
{
    int result = (*fIter)(test1, test2);
    cout << result << endl;
}


    system("PAUSE");
}

int test(int x, int y)
{
    if (y != 0)
    {
        cout << "Modulo of one and two is: " << x % y << "\n\n";
    return x % y;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Cannot divide by zero.\n\n";
        return -1;
    }
}

int add2(int x, int y)
{
    cout << "Adding " << x << " and " << y << ": ";
    return (x + y);
}

int subtract(int x, int y)
{
    cout << "Subtracting " << x << " and " << y << ": ";
    return (x - y);
}

int mult(int x, int y)
{
    cout << "Multiplying " << x << " and " << y << ": ";
    return (x * y);
}

int divide(int x, int y)
{
    if (y != 0)
    {
        cout << "Dividing " << x << " and " << y << ": ";
        return (x / y);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Cannot divide by zero.\n";
        return -1;
    }
}
```

For example, with test1 = 6 and test2 = 8, the return values would be: 6, 6, 0, "Cannot divide by zero." -1.

I also tried this: (**fIter)(test1, test2). I thought that maybe I didn't dereference enough and needed to dereference the pointer to the function as well as the iterator, but it resulted in the same output.

Thank you.

Comment: That is not the output from the above code: http://ideone.com/Yav1Eg.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce.](http://rextester.com/RGYLO13462)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That is so weird that it gives the right output because I keep getting the wrong output when I run it on my compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me, I think possibly you mixed up your variables inside your iteration (replaced test2 to with test3)

```
for (fIter = ptrsToFuncs.begin(); fIter != ptrsToFuncs.end(); ++fIter)
{
int result = (*fIter)(test1, test3);
cout << result << endl;
}
```

would give you

6, 6, 0, "Cannot divide by zero." -1.

If you need to see what your code is doing, try replacing your variables with literals and also adding some couts to your function calls.

```
 for (fIter = ptrsToFuncs.begin(); fIter != ptrsToFuncs.end(); ++fIter)
{
int result = (*fIter)(12, 24);
cout << result << endl;
}

int add2(int x, int y)
{
cout<<"add function called with first variable"<<x<<" and second variable"<<y<<endl;
return (x + y);
}
```

Comment: I definitely didn't mix up the variables--I just checked again, but I'll try the outputs and see what happens.

Comment: So I tried the output thing like you said with the same variables, 6 and 8, and for what was supposed to be the y argument (test2 = 8) it said 0 in the output! I changed test2 to be a literal of 8, and same thing. Output: "Adding 6 and 0: 6"